# Dodgy List comprehension: should this code be accepted?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

```hs
comp5 :: [ Either Int Int ]
comp5 =  [   Right x | {- Just y <- Just 2, -}  let x = 5, y <- [x, undefined]   ]
                       --           ^^ rejected: RHS must be list, `let` accepted
```

- The commented-out `Just y <- Just 2` is rejected type error because the RHS is not a list -- ok.
- The `let x = 5` is accepted, even though there's no generator to its left -- expected?
- The `y <- ...` is accepted but with a warning `Defined but not used:` -- ok.
- `comp5`'s value is `[Right 5,Right 5]` -- is that what you expected?
- ... because the `y <- ...` generates from a list with two elements, even though `y` is not used anywhere. So it's acting as a 'multiple generator'; even though there's no generator to its left.

(I was playing with dodgy/degenerate List comps because they seem to behave counter-intuitively in contrast to `do` blocks or pattern-guards. `do` blocks follow scoping left to right (top to bottom), with `return` at the end; guards scope l-to-r from `<pattern> | <guards> -> <result>`; in both, there's only a single pass through the sequence of code. )

What's the way to model this List-comp behaviour in my head, to stop my brain exploding?

**Addit:** (seeing @leftroundabout's answer)

It seems pathological to merely give a warning for `y` unused. (I had to switch on `-W` to see it.) I think GHC should shout louder if the unused var is bound from a generator.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted version `[Right x | let x = 5, y <- [x, undefined]]` is equivalent to a `do` block in the list monad:

```
   do
    let x = 5
    y <- [x, undefined]
    return (Right x)
```

which in turn is equivalent to

```
   let x = 5 in concatMap (\y -> [Right x]) [x, undefined]
```

or, since `concatMap` just unwraps the singleton list again,

```
   let x = 5 in map (const $ Right x) [x, undefined]
```

Thanks to non-strictness, `const (Right x) foo` terminates giving `Right x` even if `foo` is bottom, so the whole thing is simply two copies of `Right x`.

You can't use `Just y <- Just 2` because `Just 2` is not a list. You *could* write it

```
   [ Right x | Just y <- [Just 2], let x = 5 ]
```

or, more interestingly,

```
   [ Right x | Just y <- [Just 2, Nothing], let x = 5 ]
```

both of which would yield only `[Right 5]` since the pattern match suceeds only for one of the list elements.

Comment: It's not that I want to produce this result; it's more I was surprised the code even compiled, let alone produced a result with multiple identical elements. So thanks, the `do` block equivalent with explicit `return` makes it easier to see what's going on; but see my Addit comment in the q.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems pathological to merely give a warning for y unused. (I had to switch on -W to see it.) I think GHC should shout louder if the unused var is bound from a generator.

For better or worse, GHC by-default is not in the business of throwing errors for things that are technically valid but in practice are probably unintentional (such as defining a variable and then not using it). The type system detects situations where you are slightly inconsistent and will complain about those, but defining a variable and not using it is not an inconsistency.

Note that list comprehensions are not really seen as something completely special in Haskell; their meaning is defined via a straightforward translation into other syntactic features, and they are expected to behave the same way<sup>1</sup>. It's valid to bind variables and then not use them elsewhere, so why wouldn't that be valid in a list comprehension?

GHC *can* be pickier about "code smells" like this if you run with `-Wall -Werror` (and a lot of Haskellers code under those rules as standard). That would throw an error for your original code; you would be required to write `_ <- [x, undefined]` to explicitly say you were ignoring the values if that's what you did actually want to happen. But that's not what the language spec says and it's not what GHC has ever done by default. So it would in fact be surprising if GHC with no flags threw an error on your original code, rather than the lack of error being "pathological".

---

<sup>1</sup> In particular a generator is translated into `concatMap` applied to a let-bound local function, where the function's argument pattern is the pattern used in the generator. In your case:

```
[ Right x | let x = 5, y <- [x, undefined] ]
```

is equivalent to:

```
let x = 5
 in let ok y = [Right x]
     in concatMap ok [x, undefined]
```

So the list comprehension should be just as valid as the function `ok y = [Right x]` that doesn't use its argument. Both are *better* written as binding `_` rather than binding `y`, but both are *valid* and should not be errors (without explicit configuration to error on `Defined but not used` warnings).

See https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11 for the full official translation. Note that this isn't necessarily how list comprehensions are **implemented**, just that they are required to behave consistently with the stated identities.